# ScrollView: Button is not visible completely

Tags: android, android-layout, button, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a Problem with one activity xml in my Android project. 
Its a ScrollView and inside i have a LinearLayout. In the LinearLayout i added a Button.
But the button is not completely visible. Only 2px or like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_one"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Titel"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textview_titel"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textview_description"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_zum_gewinnspiel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="ZUM GEWINNSPIEL"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: 2px vertical? test with padding bottom in LinearLayout. I don't understand where is your ListView.

Comment: Sorry. I edit it, its a Linear Layout

Comment: well, I think that with marinbottom in the LinearLayout, it will work.

Comment: Yep. It works.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `bottomPadding` in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: It doesnt work. I added     android:paddingBottom="10dp"